# PHP larger grids (or jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to jump into PHP and I want to move a current web app to it.  The problem is this app had very large grids that rendered from database tables with a lot of fields (one of which was almost 100 fields).

I'd like a flexible, good looking, and easy to use grid that can do filtering, grouping, etc..  Very important is that I can inline edit specific columns just by clicking the cell (still can't do this right in .net).

What are my options?  THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is an excellent grid based upon the jQuery framework. Have a look at their [online demo's](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) - in particular Row Editing | Input Types.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your looking for complete solution to your backend - then you might be interested in [adminer editor](http://www.adminer.org/en/editor/) script. Otherwise there's no publicly known solution to do so - the rendering itself is quite trivial, however the main part of inline editing remains in the inline javascript as well. If this does not fulfill your question, please provide more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Yahoo User Interface for dealing with grids and general display items. You sometimes have to write your own event handlers to deal with specific behaviors, but in general it gives nice clean UI for a cheap coding investment.

The datatable can probably help you alot
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/